# Probability calculations of a winning table with multiple wild symbols

Tags: probability

We have 3 dice. Each a regular die with 6 faces 1 to 6. We create a game with pay-table A below. when we throw the dice, the winning line combination that is higher in the pay-table wins. We can calculate the probabilities of each line in the pay-table easily by calculating the probability of each then deducting the probability of higher winnings of the same symbols. So probability of the first winning line in pay-table A is $ \frac{1}6*\frac{1}6*\frac{1}6 $. Second winning line, we deduct the previous win because it uses the same symbols so $ (\frac{1}6*\frac{1}6)-(\frac{1}6*\frac{1}6*\frac{1}6) $. And so on.

Pay-table A:
1) 1,1,1
2) 1,1,- ('-' is anything except 1)
3) 1,-,-
4) 2,2,2
5) 2,2,- ('-' is anything except 2)
Notes: All in order from left to right. 2,-,2 is not considered as 2,2,- and is not counted
**Question 1:**
Say we replace the face numbered 1 with a joker on all 3 dice and we now have pay-table B below. Subtracting the probabilities of the previous winnings suddenly becomes difficult. How can we figure the probabilities of the jokers of higher winnings? In other words, line 4,4,4 in this table has less probability than 3,3,3 how can we calculate that?

Pay-table B:
1) J,J,J (J=joker)
2) 2,2,2 (2=2 or joker, but at least one real 2)
3) 3,3,3 (3=3 or joker, but at least one real 3)
4) J,J,- ('-' in this line, *in this table*, is anything except joker or 2 or  3 or 4)
5) 2,2,- ('-' here is anything except 2 or joker)
6) 4,4,4 (Note: This has less probability than 3,3,3)
7) 3,3,- ('-' here is anything except 3 or joker)
8) 2,-,- (Note: this has more prob than 3,-,- below because there are no 5's and 6's in the table)
9) 3,-,-
Notes: Combination example J,J,2 will not be considered as J,J,- but will be considered as 2,2,2. Combination J,3,J = 333. Combination J,J,5 = J,J,- because in this table there is no 5,5,5.

**Question 2:**
What if we replace another face on all 3 dice with another joker? Say 2 becomes another joker. We now have 2 different jokers: joker1 and joker2, both interchangeable, and we have pay-table C. Is there a way to calculate this table's winnings probabilities?
Pay-table C:
1) J,J,J (J can be joker1 or joker2)
2) 3,3,3 (3 can be 3 or joker1 or joker2, but at least one real 3. J1,3,J2 = 3,3,3)
3) J,J,- ('-' in this line, *in this table*, is anything except jokers or 3 or 4)
4) 3,3,- ('-' here is anything except 3 or joker1 or joker2)
5) 4,4,4 (Note: *This here has less probability than if it was above 3,3,-*)
6) 4,4,-
7) 5,-,-
**It is not as simple as it might seem** We cannot just calculate probability of each line independently. And it is not homework, I am too old for that :) It is a work project and **research** actually. I am now doing brute force using an efficient multi-threaded C++ program but I have to solve much more than this simplified example, and I have to change the pay-table and repeat over and over again. It takes a long time. Correct probability calculation will save me a lot of time, I tried very hard to find a formula but could not. If you can, I will be forever grateful :), and surely many other people will profit from it.
**Solutions** (simulation results):
Pay-table A: 1, 5, 30, 1, 5
Pay-table B: 1, 7, 7, 3, 12, 6, 12, 40, 24
Pay-table C: 8, 19, 12, 15, 15, 15, 60

Comment: You really should use different symbols for things like "2 or joker" and "3 or joker" rather than using 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, actually, the real situation has more than 3 symbols per combination and 4 or more wilds in the whole, I tried replacing every combination with the different combinations of wilds, I ended up with about 10,000 different combinations which also slowed down the probability calculation considerably.. There's got to be an algorithm for this. Must need some great mathematical brain..:)

Comment: The probabilities in your question are not difficult to calculate at all. For example, if we let $y$ be the symbol for "$2$ or joker", then your combination "$yyy$ with at least one $2$" has probability $\frac{2^3-1}{6^3} = \frac{7}{216}$. People are just not answering because the question is not interesting.

Comment: Thank you again, so, in my second question with 2 wilds, if y="2 or joker1" and z="2 or joker2", we will need combination lines of 1)y,y,z  2)y,z,y, etc just to solve my 2,2,2 line? no formula?

Comment: Your second question doesn't have a "$2,2,2$" line. Did you mean the "$3,3,3$" line that says "$3$ can be $3$ or joker1 or joker2, but at least one real $3$"?

Comment: Yes I am sorry I meant 3,3,3 becomes a long list of lines of yyz,yzy,yzz,zyy, zyz,etc.. just to solve my 333 line, then, each other line below again will have another list of replacements. In real tests, with 5 symbols per line and 4 wilds, I got about 10,000 lines, which is slowing down everything considerably.

Comment: I am running the calculations on an efficient multi-threaded C++ program, problem is, the "dice" configuration changes and number of wild too, and all probs have to be calculated again, and this has to be repeated many thousand times. it is taking many hours. A formula should save a huge amount of time.

Comment: There is no need to do it that way. Let $z$ be the symbol for "$3$ or joker" (since you said the two jokers are interchangeable). There are three ways for each die to show a $3$ or a joker, so the combination $zzz$ with no restrictions has probability $\frac{3^3}{6^3}$. However, there are $2$ ways for each die to show a joker, and thus $2^3$ ways to get only jokers. Thus, if you want at least one $3$, the probability is $\frac{3^3-2^3}{6^3} = \frac{19}{216}$.

Comment: Thank you very much Bames, now if you can explain the next line, I will understand the whole, next line is 3,3,x we will have to subtract the prob of the previous line and the prob of 3,x,3 and x,3,3 I guess?

Comment: Your combination $zzx$ with no restrictions has probability $\frac{3^3}{6^3} = \frac{1}{8}$. Notice that, once again, there are three ways for each of the first two die to show a $3$ or joker. In addition, there are three ways for the last die to show anything else ($4$, $5$, or $6$). So there are $3^3$ ways to get the combination $zzx$.

Comment: Thank you @bames, so, for 2 wilds, y=3 or joker, z=4 or joker:

Comment: What is the combination you are asking about?

Comment: prob yyy = $(3^3-2^3)/6^3=19/216$ (sorry it is not allowing me to write more than 1 line at a time..)

Comment: prob yyx =$(3^3/6^3) - (19/216)$ which is the prob of yyy?

Comment: and prob zzz = prob yyy and prob zzx = prob yyx?

Comment: Before I reply, what is $x$ here?

Comment: x is anything else, Instead of x I should write '-'

Comment: I mean : prob yy- should be $3^3 - (3^3-2^3)$ because inside prob yy- there is yyy no?

Comment: So by $-$, you mean anything _including_ $3$'s and jokers? You need to be very clear about these things.

Comment: sorry, so in combinations that have y= 3 or joker, '-' will be anything except 3 or joker. in combinations that have z= 4 or joker, '-' will be anything except 4 or joker. the table is  yyy  yy-  zzz  zz-  now in  prob yy- I think we should subtract prob yyy  and in zz- those wilds will serve inside yyy,yy-,zzz,and zz-, so we need to subtract those probs too. No?

Comment: First, the combination $yyy$ has probability $\frac{3^3}{6^3} = \frac{1}{8}$ if you have two jokers on each die. It is the combination "$yyy$ with at least one three" that has probability $\frac{19}{216}$. 

Second, the combination $yy-$ also has probability $\frac{1}{8}$. I don't know why you think subtraction is necessary. $yyy$ is not "inside" $yy-$. Notice that $JJ3$ (where $J$ means joker) is an example of $yyy$ and not $yy-$. Similarly, $3J6$ is an example of $yy-$ but not $yyy$. Neither one is "inside" the other.

For $zzz$ and $zz-$, you get probability $\frac{1}{8}$ for each.

Comment: I thank you so much for bearing with me @bames. I am forever grateful to you. I was doing it wrong, I was calculating probs with '-' = "anything" and then subtracting all previous probabilities to get the correct answers, but that was complicated when adding wilds. From our discussion I learned how to use '-'= "anything except the symbol", so I dont need to subtract anything and it can be calculated easily. You solved my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Im glad I was able to help! :)

Comment: @bames, it is more complicated than this.. I may have oversimplified my question. There are occurrence priorities. Consider my question2 above: probs are resp: 8,19,27,54,9. However, when inserting JJ- immediately under 333 they become: 12,19,12,15,54,9. notice how prob of 33x (33-) changed. This is still easy to calculate, but when you have more dice and you want to calculate combinations further down, depending on combinations above... There's got to be an algorithm.

Comment: sorry I meant they become: 8,19,12,15,54,9

Comment: What are these "occurrence priorities"? What do you mean by "inserting $JJ-$ immediately under $333$"? And how did you get $\frac{54}{6^3}$ for the probability of "$3xx$"?

Comment: @bames, Thank you for looking into this again. Consider this a game and the list under question2 a winning table. We throw the dice, the higher combination wins, so JJJ has higher priority than 333, and 333 is higher than 33x, and so on. Whichever comes first in the list is the winner. So by inserting JJ- under 333 (above 33x) We give priority to JJ- over 33x. This lowers the prob of 33x. How to get 54 for 3xx is exactly my question. Simulation, which deducts previous combinations (higher combinations in the list), gives 54. I need to be able to calculate this.

Comment: Actually 54=3x3x6, I am doing large sprite-sheets testing the results of different simulations, many numbers correlate, but still could not find a clear formula

Comment: What are you calculating the probability of for each of these combinations? It's not clear from what you've said so far.

Comment: The list in question2 is a winning table, listed in descending priority, I am calculating the probability of each line in this table will win.. So if we use all 216 combinations of the dice, how many times line1 will win, how many times line2 will win, etc...

Comment: Then if $JJJ$ is at the top of the list, shouldn't it have probability $1$ of winning? Why do you have $\frac{8}{6^3}$?

Comment: Because in the 216 different combinations of the dice it comes 8 times. 333 comes 19 times, etc. so $8/(6^3)$, $19/(6^3$), etc..

Comment: Yes, but those are not the _probabilities of winning_. They are just the probabilities of getting the combinations $JJJ$ and $333$. You need to know _exactly_ what you want to calculate the probability of, or you will make big mistakes.

Comment: Yes the probabilities of getting those combinations is what is needed. Lines that are not in the table, example 555, will not be considered for now. If we find a formula we can add more lines and will be able to re-calculate all easily.

Comment: I am giving up.. Calculating the probs of the winning list without jokers is working perfectly no matter how we move the winnings up and down, but it does not work when jokers are involved. I know the pros are putting the jokers as non-wild symbols in the winning list to do the calc, for example 33x becomes 33x, J3x and 3Jx. This is for 1 joker. When there are many jokers, we get a lot of lines to replace just 33x. I get over 10k lines when there are 5 dice, a few dozen original winning lines, and 3 jokers. But I guess this is the way we have to do it. Thank you for your patience @bames

Comment: @bames, I am very sorry my question was not clear in the beginning. After our discussion, I now edited the whole to clarify it. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @bames are you still there? no one answered in so long. I guess something is wrong/unclear in my questions? Or simply there is no solution?

Comment: as I mentioned before, this is not a difficult problem. You just don’t seem to have a very clear idea of exactly what it is that you want. I can’t help you if you can’t clearly articulate what you are looking for. Also, the meaning of your simulation results at the bottom of your question is unclear. What are those numbers? How did you get them?

Comment: @Bames, thank you for looking into this again. To clarify, we need the probabilities of the winnings in a "table". the table has priorities, the first winning line in the table has the highest priority. So if the first winning line happens, the winning lines below do not happen. I can calculate probs of winning lines when there are no jokers in the game (Pay-table A), by deducting the probs of above winning lines in the table.

Comment: But in Pay-table B for example, winning line 6) has less probability than winning lines 2) and 3) simply because it is lower in the Pay-table. Actually it is because of winning line 4) above it which reduces the chances of jokers going down the list. **I dont know how to calculate the probability of jokers taken away at winning-line 4) from winning-line 6)** Under "Solutions" each Pay-table is a different game. The numbers are the actual occurences of each winning line in the Pay-table after simulating all combinations of the dice for that game.

Comment: @bames, sorry for the late reply but I did not get a notification, just saw the messages recently